# search for alphabetic pattern in text

Tags: string, algorithm, search

I have a variable that its value is text like `$text = "I take a ball carefully to its place ...";`. I want to search for the longest substring of this string that its words start in alphabetic order.

For example, the text above should return the `a ball carefully` part, because there are 3 words starting with a... b... c... pattern (**a** **b**all **c**arefully). Legal pattern shouldn't start from *A*, its can be also like "**g**o **h**ell **i**f **j**ail" starting from any letter.

what is the most efficient way the search for it?

Comment: Compare the first character of each word while traversing the text and increment a counter when the current character is next to the previous character in the ascii order. Reset the counter to 1 when you encounter a character that is not next in the ascii order. Track the indices at which you get the maximum counter value. The substring between those indices is the result.

Comment: @SomeDude that doesn't guarantee the longest substring, only the maximum count of words.

Comment: Of course @גלעדברקן is right, there was inaccurate terminology usage in the term "longest substring". Indeed, my question was as SomeDude understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution Idea:**

Compare the first character of each word while traversing the text and increment a counter when the current character is next to the previous character in the ascii order. Reset the counter to 1 when you encounter a character that is not next in the ascii order. Track the indices at which you get the maximum counter value. The substring between those indices is the result.

**Longest substring formed by alphabetically sorted words**:

Count each word considering the length of each one and maximize the total length of the words as in:

```
def get_longest_substring_with_alphabetically_sorted_words(text):
  words = re.split(r"\s+", text)
  start = 0
  end = 0
  start_max = start
  end_max = end
  ch = words[0][0]
  c = len(words[0])
  mx = 0
  for i in range(1,len(words)):
    if ord(ch) + 1 == ord(words[i][0]):
      c += len(words[i])
      if c > mx:
        mx = c
        end = i
        start_max = start
        end_max = end
    else:
      start = i
      end = i
      c = len(words[i])
      if c > mx:
        mx = c
        start_max = start
        end_max = end
    ch = words[i][0]
  return (' '.join(words[start_max:end_max+1]))
```

**Input**:

```
1. text = "a bee can do ever for supercalifragilisticexpialidocious verb"
2. text = "a bee can do supercalifragilisticexpialidocious tea"
```

**Output**:

```
1. supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
2. supercalifragilisticexpialidocious tea
```

**Longest list of alphabetically sorted words**:

Count each word as 1 unit and maximize the length of the list of words as in :

```
import re
def get_longest_alphabetical_words(text):
    words = re.split(r"\s+", text)
    c = 1
    start = 0
    end = 0
    start_max = start
    end_max = end
    ch = words[0][0]
    mx = 0
    for i in range(1, len(words)):
        if ord(ch) + 1 == ord(words[i][0]):
            c += 1
            if c > mx:
                mx = c
                end = i
                start_max = start
                end_max = end
        else:
            start = i
            end = i
            c = 1
        ch = words[i][0]

    return ' '.join(words[start_max:end_max + 1])


text = 'I take a ball carefully to its place ... go hell if jail'
print(get_longest_alphabetical_words(text))
```

**Input:**

```
text = "I take a ball carefully to its place ... go hell if jail"
```

**Output**:

```
go hell if jail
```

Comment: This fails for input "a bee can do supercalifragilisticexpialidocious tea." The longest substring where the first letter of words ascend alphabetically is the last two words.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I thought the OP wanted longest list of alphabetically arranged words, but I added the answer to get the longest substring of alphabetically arranged words as well. Thanks.

Comment: Of course @גלעדברקן is right, there was inaccurate terminology usage in the term "longest substring". Indeed, my question was as SomeDude understood. Thank to both you!

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this by collecting all sentences with alphabetical order and then find the maximum from candidates.

I provide you a complete example in Java.
You can copy and paste in an online java compiler to see results.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "I take a ball carefully to its place go hell if jail";
        String[] arr = input.split("\\s+");    
        
        ArrayList<String> candidates = new ArrayList();
        
        String temp = "";
        String longest = "";
        char lastWord = 0;
        int maxLen = 0;

        for (String s : arr) {

            if(s.charAt(0) == lastWord+1) {
                temp += " " + s;
            }else{
                candidates.add(temp);
                temp = s;
            }
            lastWord = s.charAt(0);
        }
        
        candidates.add(temp);
        
        
        for(String candid: candidates){
            
            String trim = candid.trim();
            if (trim.isEmpty())
                continue;
                
            int len = trim.split("\\s+").length; // separate string around spaces

            if(len > maxLen) {
                longest = trim;
                maxLen = len;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Hello World: " + candidates);
        System.out.println("Hello World: " + longest);
    }
}
```